# How i return a string in a function cpp

Tags: c++, string, function, compiler-errors, return-value

I created a function that reads a JSON to set my screen in OpenCV, but when it returns a string, it gives the following error:

> ```
> In member function ‘std::__cxx11::string JsonControl::GetJson(std::__cxx11::string)’:
> /home/developer/Documents/Develloper/Kamino_Project/kamino_vizualization/modules/drivenet/src/json/read_json.cpp:27:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
> }
> ```

```
string JsonControl::GetJson(string getData)
{
   read_json("../modules/src/json/resources.json", root);

   BOOST_FOREACH (boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type &v, root.get_child(getData))
   {
       std::cout << v.second.data() << std::endl;

       stringstream geek(v.second.data());

       geek >> returnValue;

       return returnValue;
   }
}

string JsonControl::SetDataJson(string setData){
  returnValue = GetJson(setData);
  return returnValue;
}
```

Thank you very much....

Comment: What happens if the loop executes 0 times?  What do you return?

Comment: Move `return returnValue;` out of the `BOOST_FOREACH` block, hopefully you've declared and initialized `returnValue` elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you, you two are right. it is Working. I learned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trouble is that `BOOST_FOREACH` is a type of *loop,* meaning it will execute the body for each item in the tree that matches. Since it return a value on match, only the first one will be actioned.

However, if there are *no* matches, the body of the `BOOST_FOREACH` will execute exactly *zero* times so the `return` within the loop will never execute. In other words, it will fall out of the `BOOST-FOREACH` at which point there is no `return` statement returning a value to the caller.

To solve this, you could throw an exception, or return a default value, or any number of other things depending on your needs. For example, the "default value" option could go something like:

```
std::string JsonControl::GetJson(const std::string &key, const std::string &defaultVal) {
    read_json("../modules/src/json/resources.json", root);

    BOOST_FOREACH (boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type &v, root.get_child(getData)) {
        stringstream geek(v.second.data());
        geek >> returnValue;
        return returnValue;
    }

    return defaultValue;
}
```